# Should we tag questions about established (indie) RPG systems with [indie-rpg]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the [indie-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indie-rpg) tag has two distinct purposes.

1. As a tag alongside another system tag, where that system happens to be an independent RPG. For example: a portion of our [dread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dread) and [freemarket](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freemarket) questions. It also happens to be used on its won in a couple of questions - on the [Do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/) and [Engel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/) systems - which might've been in this category but had their system tag disappear.
2. More popularly, it's a tag for questions about developing an indie RPG, e.g. how to publicise it or publish it or various other stuff involved.

Is use #1 how this tag should actually get used? Should we make this tag be just about #2?

Comment: Related prior (but apparently nondecisive) discussion on this tag: [How should we use the indie tag?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21/1204)

Answer (score 6):

2 only, usage per 1 is a redundant and meta tag and should be removed when found.

If a game is just about octaNe, adding indie-RPG has no value.  If it's about writing or marketing or communities or whatnot it's a meaningful differentiator.  But we don't label every 3.5e rules question with "trad" (or "rules") - doing so fails to apprehend the reasons we have tagging on the site.

Comment: Usage per 2 is effectively redundant too: every user asking publishing questions is asking because they're publishing independently, and no non-indie publishers are going to ask here about publishing their games.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I disagree because of how "indie" is used in RPGs - it doesn't really just mean a small independent game, like two guys publishing an OSR retroclone would not normally be described as "indie," it's more for "hippie-dippy FORGE type games" and thus conveys more information about intent.

Answer (score 5):

It's a useless tag. Its meaning is too varied.

Historically, I think it was added as a placeholder for tags of infrequently asked-about games, something that could stick around when the game's actual tag vanished when StackExchange cleaned it away due to apparent rarity and disuse.

Let's just get rid of it.

Comment: It does seem like we can just retag all 28 questions in there with either: (a) the [[tag:game-design]] tag, (b) a tag for the system concerned, or (c) just removing the tag altogether.